# Windows system proxy has no effect?

Tags: windows, windows-10, proxy

I've manually configured a proxy in Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation according to the steps given on [this page](https://www.dummies.com/article/technology/computers/operating-systems/windows/windows-10/how-to-set-up-a-proxy-in-windows-10-140262/) and any number of other websites, but none of my web requests are hitting the proxy.

[image]

I'm running mitmproxy locally, and it does log requests successfully when I configure the proxy in my browser or when I specify it in a curl command, e.g. `curl --ssl-no-revoke -x 127.0.0.1:8080 https://github.com`. But when I don't configure the browser/curl to use the proxy, mitmproxy doesn't log any requests.

How can I get the entire system to use the proxy I've configured?

Comment: The Windows proxy setting is not magic. Software needs to look at it. Is your browser correctly configured? `curl` almost certainly does not look at this setting, ever.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel B. Alas. If anyone knows of a way to proxy all web traffic on a Windows machine, do please share.